# Internet Explorer IE 9+ javascript not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got a flash music player (audioplay) on a site (yeah, I know, I hate music on websites too, but the client wants it).

I'm using javasript to trigger "stop" and "play" and it works on every browser except IE 9+.
The error in IE's developer says: **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'stopMusic'**

Here's the javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function getPlayer(movieName)
    {
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) 
        {
            return window[movieName];
            } 
        else 
        {
            return document[movieName];
            }
        }

function play2()
        {
                getPlayer('player2').playMusic();
        }

        function stop2()
        {
                getPlayer('player2').stopMusic();
        }

</script>
```

Here's the working example: http://www.paulgregoryphotography.com

Answer (score 0):

use modified script

```
function getPlayer(movieName)
{
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) 
    {
        return window.document[movieName];
        } 
    else 
    {
        return document[movieName];
        }
    }
```

It works for me on IE9